# How to print x times "Hello world" by asking with an external function call, which is written in another c++ file (2 files in total)

Tags: c++, function, printing, external

How to solve it with two cpp files?
how to print x times "Hello world" by asking with an external function call, which is written in another c++ file?

function.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

int intf(void) {
    int l;
printf("How many lines to print?");
scanf("%d", &l);
printf("%d lines to print.\n", l);
int i = 0;
while (i<l) {
        printf("Hello world\n");
    i++;
}
return l;
}
```

how to solve main.cpp

Comment: do you want 2 files one containing main() and the other containing function to call, or are you trying to execute one c++ program using another c++ program

Comment: i need to solve it by calling an external function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called separate compilation and is commonly used in medium to large programs.

Here main.cpp could be as simple as:

```
int intf(void)

int main() {
    intf();
    return 0;
}
```

If you are using an IDE, just declare both source files in the same project, if you use a CLI compiler, just compile both into one executable. This could be the command on a Unix-like system:

```
c++ main.cpp function.cpp -o foo
```

But in that case you should learn what a makefile is...